# spring boot and jpa repository dealing with multi-thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, locking, spring-data-jpa

I was studying spring boot and jpa repository and encountered one issue when dealing with multi-thread.

There are 500 OfferCode in the database, by default, the allocatedFlag is set to null and the model is "ABC", and the code is unique in all 500 records.  The goal I am trying to achieve here is to call the register method to consume the OfferCode and set the allocatedFlag to 1.
The problem I got here is this line

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" offer code "+offerCode.getCode()+" "+offerCode.getAllocatedFlag());
```

Sometimes it prints the different thread name but with same code and allocatedFlag is null. Since I am using synchronized, I think ideally it should not happen.
If findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel is executed correctly, once the OfferCode is returned, the allocatedFlag will be set to 1, and then second thread comes in it should not get the same code as last thread.
But now I got
For thread A, I got for example,

```
Thread-A 0000-0000-00001 null
Thread-A 0000-0000-00001 1
```

And for thread B, I got for example,

```
Thread-B 0000-0000-00001 null
Thread-B 0000-0000-00001 1
```

I think it should get

```
Thread-B 0000-0000-00002 null
Thread-B 0000-0000-00002 1
```

So I am not sure whether I use synchronized correctly or there are some issue with JpaRepository

I also found if I change the OfferCodeRepository to below, then it is working.  So anybody know what is the issue here?

```
@Repository
public interface OfferCodeRepository extends JpaRepository<OfferCode, Integer>{
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
    Optional<OfferCode> findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel(String model);
}
```

My code

```
@Entity
public class OfferCode {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Version
    private int version;    
    private String model;
    private String code;
    private String allocatedFlag;
}

@Repository
public interface OfferCodeRepository extends JpaRepository<OfferCode, Integer>{
    Optional<OfferCode> findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel(String model);    
}

@Service
public class OfferCodeServiceImpl implements OfferCodeService {
    @Autowired
    private OfferCodeRepository offerCodeRepository;
    @Override
    public Optional<OfferCode> findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel(String model) {
        return offerCodeRepository.findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel(model);
    }
    @Override
    public OfferCode update(OfferCode code) {
        return offerCodeRepository.saveAndFlush(code);
    }
}

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private OfferCodeService offerCodeService;

    @Transactional
    public synchronized Product register(Product product) {
        if(product!=null){
            Optional<OfferCode> optional =  offerCodeService.findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel(product.getModel());
            optional.ifPresent(offerCode->{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" offer code "+offerCode.getCode()+" "+offerCode.getAllocatedFlag());
                offerCode.setAllocatedFlag("1");
                offerCodeService.update(offerCode); 
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" offer code "+offerCode.getCode()+" "+offerCode.getAllocatedFlag());
            });

        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `synchronized` to solve this. It might at first sound like a good idea, but then you are deploying multiple instances of your application/service... Then how is `synchronized` going to help you? Let the database solve this for you. Next to that you are already using `@Version` so you have optimistic locking. So if it really was to happen 1 would fail with an exception. Using the database with locks (as you have with the `PESSIMISTIC_READ`) is the correct way to solve this. But it can be quite an impact on performance.

Comment: The data base I am using is mysql.

Comment: If I use below code
findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel(String model);
public synchronized Product register
I see Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.example.domain.OfferCode#462]
If I use 
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
findTop1ByAllocatedFlagIsNullAndModel(String model);
public Product register(Product product)
I see
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Comment: Well yes, as mentioned you are either using optimistic locking (which will give yuo an exception if something else modified the entity, the other one is pessimistic which will give you a deadlock (or waits depending on the strategy/timeout).